# Taking 3 array elements and making them a single formatted string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running an ajax request that returns JSON data:

```
{
"error":0,
"fleet":[
  {
     "fleet_uid":859805,
     "purpose":0,
     "ower":1,
     "time":520,
     "con_time":647,
     "from":[
        6,
        300,
        2
     ],
     "target":[
        6,
        300,
        6
     ],
     "start_user_id":20457507089,
     "target_user_id":20510481089,
     "start_planet_name":"Tweenis12",
     "target_planet_name":"P23808"
  },
  {
     "fleet_uid":859803,
     "purpose":0,
     "ower":1,
     "time":508,
     "con_time":647,
     "from":[
        6,
        300,
        2
     ],
     "target":[
        6,
        300,
        6
     ],
     "start_user_id":20457507089,
     "target_user_id":20510481089,
     "start_planet_name":"Tweenis12",
     "target_planet_name":"P23808"
  }
],
"count":2
}
```

I need to get only the target information inside the fleet property. Depending on the time, there might be no fleet entries and there might be 10+.

Inside the target property is 3 entries. I need to merge those 3 entries into a single string formatted like xx_xxx_xx

Being so unfamiliar with JS and jQuery, I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
var json = {"error":0,"fleet":[{"fleet_uid":859805,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":520,"con_time":647,"from":[6,300
,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name":"Tweenis12"
,"target_planet_name":"P23808"},{"fleet_uid":859803,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":508,"con_time":647,"from"
:[6,300,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name"
:"Tweenis12","target_planet_name":"P23808"}],"count":2};

var arr = [];
$.each(json.fleet, function(){
    var value = this.target;
    arr.push(value[0] + '_' + value[1] + '_' + value[2]);       
});
alert(arr);
```

demo in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/L4hwa4qe/)

Comment: Both answers were good, but this one got the effect I needed best. Thank you both!

Comment: This is good, but there is a simpler way using `map()` and `join()` without the need of jQuery and pushing to an array. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `map()` function to compile all your `target` values for each fleet item into one array. This will help a lot when you retrieve the data. The values in each `target` are joined with `_`. This method does not require jQuery.

Run the snippet below. The important piece of code is the declaration of `var targets` starting with the conditional to check that your data has the `fleet` property.

For the data you have in your question, `var targets` becomes `['6_300_6', '6_300_6']`.

```js
var data = {"error":0,"fleet":[{"fleet_uid":859805,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":520,"con_time":647,"from":[6,300
,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name":"Tweenis12"
,"target_planet_name":"P23808"},{"fleet_uid":859803,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":508,"con_time":647,"from"
:[6,300,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name"
:"Tweenis12","target_planet_name":"P23808"}],"count":2}

if (data.fleet) { 
   var targets = data.fleet.map(function (item) {
      return item.target.join('_'); 
   });
}

// for the purpose of demonstration
document.getElementById('targets').innerHTML = targets;
```

```html
var targets = [<div id="targets"></div>];
```

Comment: Isn't `data.fleet` undefined if none exists in the JSON?

Comment: If `fleet` does not exist in the JSON, you can add a conditional like `if (data.fleet) { var targets = ... ; }`. I will update my answer.

Comment: I only mentioned it because it was one of the requirements. ;) Anyhow, +1 for not using jQuery.  There's a lot that can be done using JS in the browser alone, and is usually much faster. (http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and see how I like it. This question has been a real learning experience for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

If data is the reference to the response then

```
if(data.target && data.target.length){
    data.target = target.join('_');        
}
```

---

If you want X to replace the chars then

```
var target = data.target;
if(target && target.length){
    target = target.join('_');
    target = target.replace(/\d/g, 'x')      
}
data.target = target;
```

Comment: No, the Xs where example filler since the numbers could be any number. The important thing is to be able to take multiple fleet entries with different numbers and load them into an array to pass to the next function.

Comment: Don't you mean `data.fleet[#].target`?

Answer (score 0):

Visualize your json here - http://jsonmate.com/permalink/553846afaa522bae3683edc8

It's how I first figured out the dot notation of accessing json objects in Javascript. In my code below, I follow the path through that visualization to your target objects. The fleets are arrays. The targets are also arrays.

```js
var data = {"error":0,"fleet":[{"fleet_uid":859805,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":520,"con_time":647,"from":[6,300
,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name":"Tweenis12"
,"target_planet_name":"P23808"},{"fleet_uid":859803,"purpose":0,"ower":1,"time":508,"con_time":647,"from"
:[6,300,2],"target":[6,300,6],"start_user_id":20457507089,"target_user_id":20510481089,"start_planet_name"
:"Tweenis12","target_planet_name":"P23808"}],"count":2};

var targets = []; //array of targets in fleets

for (var i = 0; i < data.fleet.length; i++)  {
  var a = data.fleet[i].target[0];
  var b = data.fleet[i].target[1];
  var c = data.fleet[i].target[2];
  var target = a + "_" + b + "_" + c;
  targets.push(target);
}

alert(targets);
```